# Can't get axis values to render on top of rect d3js v4

Tags: javascript, d3.js

In this **[plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/ilzieBZxEfOcelwd39xx?p=preview)** I'm trying to make the xAxis text (the states) render on top of the rect element.

The usual fix is to select the `.axis.axis--x` and place it after the `rect`.

I've also tried to change the z-index in various classes and elements without any success.

Anyone that knows what I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should insert your `layer` containers (which contain your rects) before x-axis. Change your code on 186-188 string this way:

```
let barGroups = g.selectAll("g.layer").data(series);
  barGroups.enter().insert("g", ".axis--x") // <== !!!
  .classed('layer', true);
```

Look at [my fork of your plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/ezZrnWeDOEGVZIFhk7BI?p=preview).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I meant something like [this](https://bl.ocks.org/LemoNode/3268356bdb351f9921eaf5a33de65b10) just to have the text in front of the rect so that it's readable, should have been more clear, my bad

Answer (score 2):

Maintaining the correct order of `<g>` elements should work just fine. You need to make sure the `<g class=".axis.axis--x">` comes after your bars in document order. There are multiple ways to achieve this; one way is to use [`selection.insert("g", ".axis.axis--x")`](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_insert) to insert the bars right before the x axis group:

```
// Stacked bars
let barGroups = g.selectAll("g.layer").data(series);
barGroups.enter().insert("g", ".axis.axis--x")
    .classed('layer', true);
```

Have a look at this working [fork](https://plnkr.co/edit/cLg4fWgOb1Cq3C1YpJeO?p=preview) of your code.